Unexpected attribute: An attribute named "default_to_oauth_authentication" is not expected here
I'm terraforming an azure storage account and the documentation says this is how to force active directory or entra ID authentication, but the vscode linter and terraform plan are rejecting it.

Terraform v1.9.7 on darwin_arm64
Provider: registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0

Tried
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  # ...
  default_to_oauth_authentication = true
}

Expected terraform plan output
result:
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on terraform.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example":
│   10:   default_to_oauth_authentication = true
│ 
│ An argument named "default_to_oauth_authentication" is not expected here.
╵


Support for the default_to_oauth_authentication property of azurerm_storage_account resource was added in azurerm v3.19.0 (see the changelog).
You must upgrade the provider in order to be able to use that property.
